# Cross-build, link issue

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker, cross-compiling

I have to build a small program to run on a set-top box, and for that I use a specific build toolchain: toolchain-final-mipsisa32r2el-timesys-linux-gnu

The build is composed of 2 parts: one lib static .a file and an executable that use the library.

The lib is correctly build with the following option:

```
mipsisa32r2el-timesys-linux-gnu-gcc -c --param max-inline-insns-single=2400 
-o ../../../build/LinuxHost_STB_release/_outLib/STB.o -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing 
-Winline -Wall -I../../../Modules -I../../../Source 
-I/opt/toolchains/toolchain-final-mipsisa32r2el-timesys-linux-gnu/include 
-I -fno-rtti ../../../Source/STBLib/STB.cpp
```

if I run `nm` on the libSTB.a, I saw the function define in STB.cpp as:

```
 0000000000000124 T STB_Create
 0000000000000460 T STB_Destroy
```

To compile and link the executable, I use the following command line:

```
mipsisa32r2el-timesys-linux-gnu-c++ -o ../../../build/LinuxHost_STB_release/STBExample 
--sysroot=/opt/toolchains/toolchain-final-mipsisa32r2el-timesys-linux-gnu/ 
-I/opt/toolchains/toolchain-final-mipsisa32r2el-timesys-linux-gnu/include 
-L../../../build/LinuxHost_STB_release 
-lSTB ../../../Source/STBLib/STBExample.c
```

But I get the following linker error:

```
STBExample.c:(.text+0x488): undefined reference to `STB_Create'
```

Any idea of where I made a mistake or on how to investigate ?

Comment: Flip the `-lSTB` and the `../../../Source/STBLib/STBExample.c` arguments.

Comment: Echoing what @H2CO3 said.  Usually, library arguments go last, especially with static libraries.

Comment: Effectively it changes the linker output, at least now I got error "undefined reference" but for internal data and function, not yet include in my file list. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @H2CO3 and @Joe Z, the problem was in the parameter ordering.
Additional static lib set with `-l`must be place AFTER the .c file. As in the following example, a switch of the 2 last arguments solved the issue.

```
mipsisa32r2el-timesys-linux-gnu-c++ -o ../../../build/LinuxHost_STB_release/STBExample 
--sysroot=/opt/toolchains/toolchain-final-mipsisa32r2el-timesys-linux-gnu/ 
-I/opt/toolchains/toolchain-final-mipsisa32r2el-timesys-linux-gnu/include 
-L../../../build/LinuxHost_STB_release 
../../../Source/STBLib/STBExample.c -lSTB
```